# CMake set target properties called with incorrect number of arguments

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I'm trying to use **OpenCV** library in my project, but I get this error at runtime :

> Build command failed. Error while executing process
>   D:\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments
>   {-HC:\Users\Mouad AITALI\AndroidStudioProjects\BGREMOVER\app
>   -BC:\Users\Mouad AITALI\AndroidStudioProjects\BGREMOVER\app.cxx\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a
>   -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Mouad AITALI\AndroidStudioProjects\BGREMOVER\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a
>   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DANDROID_NDK=D:\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\Sdk\ndk\19.2.5345600\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake
>   -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "C:/Users/Mouad AITALI/AndroidStudioProjects/BGREMOVER/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (set_target_properties):
>   set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
#declare folder path
set(pathToProject C:\\Users\\Mouad;AITALI\\AndroidStudioProjects\\BGREMOVER)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

include_directories(${pathToOpenCv}/sdk/native/jni/include)

#library location
add_library(lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${pathToProject}/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

#define libraries
add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)
add_library(grabcut SHARED src/main/cpp/jni-grabcut-lib.cpp src/main/cpp/grabcutter_p.cpp src/main/cpp/grabcutter_p.h)

find_library(log-lib log)

#target libraries
target_link_libraries(native-lib ${log-lib} lib_opencv)
target_link_libraries(grabcut ${log-lib} lib_opencv)
```

Comment: Your `pathToProject` variable has a semicolon in the path. Is this intentional?

Comment: Wrap the value of `IMPORTED_LOCATION` into **double quotes**. Do the same for `pathToProject` variable's value. Otherwise CMake treats them as a **list** because of semicolon.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you so much for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, CMake uses the semicolon `;` to define lists. So if the path contains semicolons, you must enclose the definition, and places where you use the variable `pathToProject` with double quotes:

```
set(pathToProject "C:\\Users\\Mouad;AITALI\\AndroidStudioProjects\\BGREMOVER")

...

set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${pathToProject}/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so")
```

The [`IMPORTED_LOCATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html) property only takes one value. So when you provide a list for that property, the `set_target_properties()` command cannot parse the arguments correctly, which yields the error.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I know it's should be another question but I get this now : `ninja: error: 'C:/Users/Mouad;AITALI/AndroidStudioProjects/BGREMOVER/app/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libgrabcut.so', missing and no known rule to make it`

Comment: Does the library `libopencv_java3.so` *actually* exist at that location?

Comment: On the screenshot between `Mouad` and `AITALI` there is a **space**, not a **semicolon** as you use in `pathToProject` variable.